# Passing an array as the code to eval in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, eval, settimeout

Today my friends sent my some code that did something unexpected:

`setTimeout(["console.log(1", "2)"], 1000)`

I expected this to fail or do some magic, but it just prints `1 2` after 1 second.
I can see it possibly evaluating the array to `"console.log(1,2)"` using a simple `array.join(',')`, but why does that happen?

I've looked into the eval capabilities of `setTimeout`, but it should only do a function or a string. The use of an array here doesn't make any sense, and searching Google for why this does work turns up nothing, or even close use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` can evaluate a string as javascript, if the value is not a `function` it will then convert the value to a string, probably by using `toString()`

You can see if you do this

```
"" + ["console.log(1", "2)"]
```

or

```
["console.log(1", "2)"].toString();
```

you get

```
'console.log(1,2)'
```

Then it get's evaluated accordingly

Comment: I get `'console.log(1,2)'`. Are the quotes there for a reason? If so why don't I get them with Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a function then it uses `.toString()` to get a string value.